# Ruby remove &#xD; &#xA0;

Tags: html, ruby

I am using xpath to extract first element that contain keywords from html files. But some files have &#xD &#xA0 and my code doesn't work. I want to replace &#xD &#xA0 with space but don't know how.

```
 <font size="1" face="Times New Roman" style="font-size:8.0pt;">For&#xD;
 the fiscal year ended December&#xA0;31, 2006</font>

doc.xpath('//*[contains(text(),"For the fiscal year ended")]')[0]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert to the actual value:

```
require "htmlentities"
HTMLEntities.new.decode('For&#xD; the fiscal year ended December&#xA0;31, 2006')
#=> "For\r\n the fiscal year ended December 31, 2006"
```

Doing `gsub` on `"\r\n"` and `" "` to a space will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to do it in preprocessing, before you parse it: `source.gsub!(/&#x(d|a0);/i, ' ')`