# Python remove &#xD from XML

Tags: python, xml

I'm extracting text from an XML file and printing it to a text file using python.  Some lines in the xml file have '&#xD' and '&#xA' in them which cause the line to be output to the text file with carriage returns and line feeds.  There are answers here [Ruby remove &#xD; &#xA0;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320085/ruby-remove-xd-xa0) and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794365/remove-xd-from-xml on how to remove these characters in Ruby and PHP so that there are no line breaks.  How do I do this in Python.  Here is my code

```
with open("xmlfile") as f:
    doc = parse(f)
    str = doc.getElementsByTagName("informations")[0].getAttribute("text")
    print(str)
    str = str.replace("&#xD;", " ").replace("&#xA;", " ")
    print(str)
```

Here is the string in the xml file

```
"An Airport Contact Method, Is Alter must be one of the following:&#xD;&#xA;- &quot;T&quot; or &quot;F&quot; (boolean true or false) or empty" language="en"
```

Output:

```
An Airport Contact Method, Is Alter must be one of the following:
- "T" or "F" (boolean true or false) or empty
An Airport Contact Method, Is Alter must be one of the following:
- "T" or "F" (boolean true or false) or empty
```

Comment: Please include a short, complete program that demonstrates the problem you are having. Please include the actual output of the program and the expected output. See [ask], but more specifically, [mcve].

Comment: Showing the string in the xml file isn't useful. Show what value `doc.getElementsByTagName("informations")[0].getAttribute("text")` returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time whatever XML library you're using has parsed it, it's already resolved the entities.

Replace

```
str = str.replace("&#xD;", " ").replace("&#xA;", " ")
```

with

```
str = str.replace("\r", " ").replace("\n", " ")
```

Per @martineau's suggestion, if you're ever not sure what character an XML entity is resolving to you can try `print(repr(str))` to get a better picture of what the string actually contains once it's been `parse`d.

Comment: Thank you, I started out trying something similar with str.rstrip('\r\n') but that still printed the string in two lines

Comment: @user3614578: `print(repr(str))` to see what is actually being returned by the XML library (instead of continually guessing).

Comment: That prints with \r\n in place of &#xD;&#xA;

Comment: @user3614578, that's because the `&#xD;` has been replaced with a `\r` etc.already by the time you're getting it.  The idea is that `repr` would give you the exact character instead of the XML entity